# bibtex2html - which bibstyles are acceptable? one produced by docstrip does not work

Tags: bibtex

I use bibtex2html to produce a webpage and would like to change the bibstyle. I have a style `first.bst` produced with docstrip. The command

```
bibtex2html ../frank2link.bib -s first.bst
```

nor

```
bibtex2html ../frank2link.bib -s first
```

does not work. The file first.bst is in the local directory.

What styles are accepted? Anything else I do wrong? 
Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`bibtex2html` requires strictly to have the options before the `.bib` file. Thus something like

```
bibtex2html  --title "Publicationlist xx" --style  first.bst biblio.bib
```

works.

Processing may produce errors for commands set up in the style file but not used in `bibex2html`.